# Reverse a String without affecting special characters

Tags: java, string, reverse

Why is it throwing an error? Any help would be appreciated

```
public class RAWS 
{
public String rawsc(String ori)
{
    String temp="";
    for(int i=0;i<ori.length();i++)
    {
        char c=ori.charAt(i);
        if(((c>=65)&&(c<=90))||((c>=97)&&(c<122)))
            temp=c+temp;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<ori.length();i++)
    {
        char c=ori.charAt(i);
        if(((c>=65)&&(c<=90))||((c>=97)&&(c<122)))
            ori.replace(c, temp.charAt(i));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<ori.length();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(ori.charAt(i));
    }
    return(ori);
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String str="a,b$c";
    RAWS ob=new RAWS();
    String new1=ob.rawsc(str);
    for(int i=0;i<new1.length();i++)
    {
        System.out.print(new1.charAt(i)+" ");
    }
}
}
```

Editor:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4 
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658) 
at arraygs.RAWS.rawsc(RAWS.java:22) 
at arraygs.RAWS.main(RAWS.java:30)
```

Comment: What error?????

Comment: What kind of error is thrown? Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Rolled back the edit: please keep code as **text** in the question body, not as an image.

Comment: Just a hint on Java efficiency: For the `temp` variable, use the `StringBuilder` class and its `append()` method, as repeatedly using the `+` operator on Strings creates a lot of intermediate String and StringBuilder instances (one per iteration).

Comment: Restructuring suggestion: you're trying to do two things in one method, remove the special characters and reverse the order of characters in the remaining string. Splitting that in two methods might make the job easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic part is the call `temp.charAt(i)` in

```
for(int i=0;i<ori.length();i++){
    char c=ori.charAt(i);
    if(((c>=65)&&(c<=90))||((c>=97)&&(c<122)))
        ori.replace(c, temp.charAt(i));
}
```

The string `temp` may not have the length of `ori`. The reason for this is the if-condition in the first loop

```
for(int i=0;i<ori.length();i++) {
    char c=ori.charAt(i);
    if(((c>=65)&&(c<=90))||((c>=97)&&(c<122)))
        temp=c+temp;
}
```

So accessing the position `i` in `temp` (as part of the second loop) may result in the `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thank you! It was the problem as you said, and now no errors. But still not the desire output. Maybe something is wrong logically.

Answer (score 2):

public class PracticeJava{

```
public static void main(String []args){

   String str = "\"Str!ng\"";
   System.out.println("Actual str:  "+str);
   System.out.println("Reverse str: "+reverseStrSpecial(str));

}

public static String reverseStrSpecial(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    char[] revStrArr = new char[len];
    int j = len-1;
    for (int i=0; i <= j; ) {
        if(!Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i))) {
            revStrArr[i] = str.charAt(i);
            i++;
        } else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(j))) {
            revStrArr[j] = str.charAt(j);
            j--;
        } else {
            revStrArr[j] = str.charAt(i);
            revStrArr[i] = str.charAt(j);
            j--;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return new String(revStrArr);
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't just post code. Instead explain _why_ your code solves the ops question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
 System.out.println(reverseString("a,b$c"));  
}  
/**  
* Reverse string with maintaining special character in place  
*  
* Algorithm:  
* 1. create temporary array  
* 2. copy all character from original array excluding special character  
* 3. reverse the temporary array  
* 4. start copying temporary array into original if element is an alphabetic character  
* @param input  
* @return  
*/ 
public static String reverseString(String input) {  
 char[] inputArr = input.toCharArray();  
 char[] tempArr = new char[input.length()];  
 int i=0;  
 int j=0;  
 for (char ch:inputArr){  
   if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch)){  
     tempArr[i] = ch;  
     i++;  
   }  
 }  
 i--;  
 while(j<i){  
   char temp = tempArr[i];  
   tempArr[i]= tempArr[j];  
   tempArr[j]=temp;  
   j++;  
   i--;  
 }  
 for(i=0,j=0;i<input.length();i++){  
   if(Character.isAlphabetic(inputArr[i])){  
     inputArr[i]= tempArr[j++];  
   }  
 }  
 return new String(inputArr);  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Ex {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String ss= "Hello@@#+dnksjaf#+43@##@";
char[] c=new char[ss.length()];
String spclCharLessString="";
String spclCharLessStringrev="";

for(int i=0;i<ss.length();i++) {
    if(((ss.charAt(i)>='A'&&ss.charAt(i)<='Z')|(ss.charAt(i)>='a'&&ss.charAt(i)<='z')|(ss.charAt(i)>='0'&&ss.charAt(i)<='9'))) {
        spclCharLessString+=ss.charAt(i);
    }
    c[i]=ss.charAt(i);
}
for(int i=spclCharLessString.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
    spclCharLessStringrev+=spclCharLessString.charAt(i);
}
int spclCharSpace=0;
for(int i=0;i<ss.length();i++) {
    if(((ss.charAt(i)>='A'&&ss.charAt(i)<='Z')|(ss.charAt(i)>='a'&&ss.charAt(i)<='z')|(ss.charAt(i)>='0'&&ss.charAt(i)<='9'))) {
        c[i]=spclCharLessStringrev.charAt(i-spclCharSpace);
    }else {
        spclCharSpace++;
    }

}
System.out.println(spclCharLessStringrev);
for(char c1:c) {
    System.out.print(c1);
}


}
```

}

Comment: Would you mind explaining what this does?

Answer (score 0):

using regex seems to be a good idea.here is my javascript solution.

```
var reverseOnlyLetters = function(S) {
let arr = S.split('')
let regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{1}$/
let i=0,j=arr.length-1;
while(i<j){
   if(regex.test(arr[i]) && regex.test(arr[j])){
       let temp = arr[i]
       arr[i]=arr[j]
       arr[j]=temp
       i++;j--
   }else{
       if(!regex.test(arr[i])) i++
       if(!regex.test(arr[j])) j--
   } 
}
return arr.join('')
```

};

Answer (score 0):

```
str=input("enter any string")
l=[]
s=""
list=list(str)
for i in str:
    k=ord(i)
    if((k>=48 and k<=57) or (k>=65 and k<=90) or(k>=97 and k<=122)):
        l.append(i)
l.reverse()
print(s.join(l))
```

by sreevidhya bontha

Comment: Please don't just post code. Instead explain why your code solves the ops question. And how it differs or builds on existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "fed@cb%a!";
        char arr[] = new char[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) < 48 || (str.charAt(i) > 57 && str.charAt(i) < 65) || (str.charAt(i) > 90 && str.charAt(i) < 97) || str.charAt(i) > 122)
                arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
            else
                arr[i] = '0';
        }
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
        }
        int i=0;
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            char pop = stack.pop();
            if (!(pop < 48 || (pop > 57 && pop < 65) || (pop > 90 && pop < 97) || pop > 122)){
                arr[i] = pop;
                ++i;
            }
            if(arr[i]!='0'){
                ++i;
            }
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
Time complexity: O(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "ab$cd";
        char[] b = a.toCharArray();
        int c = b.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < c / 2; i++) {
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(b[i]) || Character.isDigit(b[i])) {
                char temp = b[i];
                b[i] = b[c - i - 1];
                b[c - i - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));
}
```

Comment: This is the solution when there is only one special character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

public class MuthuTest {
    static Map list = new HashMap();

```
/*
 * public static int fact(int n) { if(n>1) return n*fact(n-1); else return 1; }
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String j = "muthu is a good boy.";
    int v = 0;
    String[] s = j.split(" ");
    for (int h = 0; h < s.length; h++) {
        String y;
        y = s[h].replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]", "");

        list.put(h, y);

    }

    // MuthuTest.li(s);
    for (int u = s.length - 1; u >= 0; u--) {
        if (u == 0) {

            s[u] = s[u].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
            System.out.print(s[u] + list.get(v));

        } else {
            s[u] = s[u].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

            System.out.print(s[u] + list.get(v) + " ");
        }

        v++;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Java] Simple way to reverse only alphabets without affecting special chars.

```
public class StringReverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       reverseString("T@E$J#A%S");
}

//S@A$JE@T
private static void reverseString(String s){
    int len = s.length();
    char[] arr = new char[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch)){
            arr[len-1-i] = ch;
        }else{
            arr[i] = ch;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(new String(arr));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;



public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        String s = "S@3jakd*nd%4*ksdkj12";
        String str = "";
        int len = s.length();

        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                str = str + s.charAt(i);
            } else {

                map.put(s.charAt(i), new Integer(s.indexOf(s.charAt(i))));

            }
        }

        for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {

            str = str.substring(0, entry.getValue()) + entry.getKey() + str.substring(entry.getValue(), str.length());

        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! To better help OP, you should add an explanation to your answer rather than just code. Try to answer the question "Why does your code solve the problem?"

Answer (score 0):

Reverse a String without affecting any special chars. Note that it is just for a String but not combination of Strings that would eventually be an array of Strings.

Code :

```
public class Info {
    
    // Input : str = "Ab,c,de!$"               o/p : ed,c,bA!$
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Ab,c,de!$";
        char[] inputCharArray = input.toCharArray();
        reverseIgnoreSpecialCharacters(inputCharArray);
        
    }
    
    public static void reverseIgnoreSpecialCharacters(char[] charArray) {
        int j = charArray.length-1;
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = charArray.length-1; i>=0;  i--) {
            if(!(charArray[i] >= 65 && charArray[i] <=90) || !(charArray[i] >= 97 && charArray[i] <=122)) {
                charArray[j] = charArray[i];
                System.out.print(charArray[j]);
                j--;
                
            }
            else {
                charArray[k] = charArray[i];
                System.out.print(charArray[k]);
                k++;
            }       
        }   
    }
}
```

for multiple Strings, you could something like below :

**Code :**

```
public class Info {
    
    // Input : str = "Ab,c,de!$"               o/p : ed,c,bA!$
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Ab,c,de!$ Abhi$hek";
        String[] inputStringArray = input.split("\\ ");
        for(int i = inputStringArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            char[] strArray = inputStringArray[i].toCharArray();
            reverseIgnoreSpecialCharacters(strArray);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void reverseIgnoreSpecialCharacters(char[] charArray) {
        int j = charArray.length-1;
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = charArray.length-1; i>=0;  i--) {
            if(!(charArray[i] >= 65 && charArray[i] <=90) || !(charArray[i] >= 97 && charArray[i] <=122)) {
                charArray[j] = charArray[i];
                System.out.print(charArray[j]);
                j--;
                
            }
            else {
                charArray[k] = charArray[i];
                System.out.print(charArray[k]);
                k++;
            }       
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Way to Do it..

```
    String name = "Ma@hb$oobSi#ddi$qui";
    char oldchararr[] = name.toCharArray();
    String newStr = new StringBuffer(name.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")).reverse().toString();
    char newchar[] = newStr.toCharArray();
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < oldchararr.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(oldchararr[i]) || Character.isDigit(oldchararr[i])) {
            oldchararr[i] = newchar[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (char c : oldchararr) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
```